# How to write a Windows Service using VB.NET + SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, vb.net, windows-services

I'm trying to build a windows service, using VB.NET that grabs new data from 4 different SQL databases via the network which I've already given DSN using ODBC for each DB. So far I was able to create a simple windows service but it's not doing what I'm trying to do.

My end goal is to connect it with 4 different SQL DB's as mentioned above, to get data every other 5 mins or so(listen to new data which added to the SQL DB's within last 5 minutes and log it in a txt log file).

This is my code,

"TestWindowsService.vb"

```
Public Class TestWindowsService

    Dim tmr As Timers.Timer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
        tmr = New Timers.Timer()
        tmr.Interval = 1000 'Setting Interval pf Timer. 1s interval
        AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf MyTimerHandler
        tmr.Enabled = True
        FileIO.WriteToFile("Service Started!" + vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        tmr.Enabled = False
        FileIO.WriteToFile("Service Stopped!" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyTimerHandler(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)
        FileIO.WriteToFile("1 sec is over!" + vbNewLine)
    End Sub
End Class
```

"FileIO.vb"

```
Public Class FileIO

    Public Shared Sub WriteToFile(strToWrite As String)
        Dim stream As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing

        Try
            stream = New IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\myFile_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt",
                                         True)
            stream.Write(strToWrite)
            stream.Flush()
            stream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

**My question is : What part from the above code should I edit so that program can listen to changes in the DB and logs to txt file every 5 minutes?**

I really appreciate your time and consideration all!

Comment: You asked this [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66985627/2029983) and it was closed. Don't delete your old question and then post it again without changing it. The close reason tells you to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66985627/edit) the question to make it on topic; do that and get your **original** question through the reopen queue.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thanks for the update. With all due respect can you please tell me clearly what's the issue with this question? I've gone through your comment last time and edited the question and reposted it according to the guidelines. From what I understood as a community we have to help each other whenever need. I'm really sorry if I'm doing something wrong here but I honestly think I've asked the question in a wrong way before and edited it now posted in a right way with adding my code which I was able to do so far.  I'm trying to learn something new from your guidance and hope for help.

Comment: *"reposted it according to the guidelines."* That isn't what the guidelines state at all. This is what the guidance you were given states: *"Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66985627/edit)."*

Comment: I edited my question and asked which focused only one problem as you mentioned :) I understood my mistake now. Thank you @Larnu

Comment: I usually don´t recommend third party tools, but [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) + [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) + [log4net](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) are way too powerful combination for your requirements to not mention them

Comment: To answer you question, won't setting  tmr.Interval = 300000 mean your event is being fired every 5mins?  Although, your solution looks quite a bit different to anything I've ever done with timers in services I'm sure you've done your research.  First thing I always do though is make sure I can get the basics running as a console app before going anywhere near a service